# Collection sorted by key via stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a simply class with three values:

```
class Book{
   private String title;
   private String author;
   private double price;
}
```

`title` is unique(always). There is a list of selected titles(as `List<String>`) and list of every `Book` in system. I want to get all `Book` with key from list of titles. My code is:

```
List<Book> allBooks = getAllBooks();
List<String> selectedTitles = getSelectedTitles();
List<Book> selectedBooks = allBooks.stream().
   filter(x -> selectedTitles.contains(x.getTitle())).
   collect(Collectors.toList());
```

it works but selectedBooks is ordered by `allBook` insted of `selectedTitles`. For example:

```
allBooks(only title) = {"A","B","C","D"}
selectedTitles = {"B","A","D"}
selectedBooks(only title) = {"A","B","D"}
```

How is it possible(via `stream()` to get ordered by `selectedTitles`? (For this example it should be `{"B","D","A"}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don’t sort, just look up the books that have been selected:

```
List<Book> allBooks = getAllBooks();
List<String> selectedTitles = getSelectedTitles();

Map<String,Book> titleToBook = allBooks.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Book::getTitle, Function.identity()));

List<Book> selectedBooks = selectedTitles.stream()
    .map(titleToBook::get).filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```